# How can we do IF condition in Excel and assign values?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, logical-operators, multiple-conditions

I want to get a formula for the below conditions:

1. null | <0.65 then 16
2. >=1.13 & <2.23 then 8
3. >=2.23 then 0

I tried:

```
=If(B3=0,16,IF (B3<0.65,16,IF (B3>=0.65,11,AND (B3<1.13,11,IF (B3>=1.13,8,AND (B3<2.23,8,If(B3>=2.23,0)))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=IF(OR(B3="",B3=0,B3<0.65),16,IF(AND(B3>=1.13,B3<2.23),8,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want this formula:

```
=IF(B3<0.65,16,IF(AND(B3>=0.65,B3<1.13),11,IF(AND(B3>=1.13,B3<2.23),8,IF(B3>=2.23,0))))
```

This will work if you have Office 2019 or 365:

```
=SWITCH(TRUE,B3<0.65,16,B3<1.13,11,B3<2.23,8,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you a formula, but a way to understand how you might solve your problem: you can use the `Evaluate formula` feature of Excel:

Go to the "Formulas" tab. This should contain a ±"Check formulas" and in there, there's the "Evaluate formula" feature.

This feature allows you to evaluate complex like yours step by step, which allows you to find where exactly your formula is wrong.

In case you still can't find out why your formula does not work, please update your question by adding for which input value (B3) you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it as follows, it worked for me. =IF(OR(B2="",B3=0,B2<0.65),16,IF(AND(B2>=0.65,B2<1.13),11,IF(AND(B2>=1.13,B2<2.23),8,0)))